# Passport Stamp in a Schengen Airport / Entry to Croatia with a Schengen Visa

Tags: visas, schengen, poland, croatia

I am a Lebanese citizen traveling from Beirut Lebanon to Zagreb Croatia with a 3-hour layover in Warsaw Poland.
I hold a multiple-entry Schengen visa issued by France that I have never used before (valid for the period of my trip).
The rules of Croatia state that I can enter the country with a valid multiple-entry Schengen visa.
I have 2 questions here:

1. Should my passport be stamped by a Schengen country before I am permitted entry to Croatia?
2. Will my passport be stamped in Poland (in and out)?

Comment: Is your trip from Beirut to Zagreb via Warsaw on one ticket, so you will only be in transit in Poland? Or is that two separate tickets?

Comment: Yes 1 ticket with LOT

Answer (score 1):

1. You are not required to have entered a Schengen country before you enter Croatia. As you already mention in the question, a multiple-entry Schengen visa is sufficient. Source: [Croatian Ministry of Foreign Affairs](http://www.mvep.hr/en/consular-information/visas/visa-requirements-overview/)
2. Receiving a stamp or not may depend on you having to clear immigration there if you need to claim and recheck bags, but it doesn't matter for your subsequent entry to Croatia.